# Drawing trees using Binary Merge

Tags: syntax, english

1. He was for sure having a difficult time.
2. what aren't the public afraid of?
3. Had this candidate waited for the results to the elections in vain?

I have to draw these using Binary Merge.

Comment: My condolences. Ask your teacher where you can buy the new Binary Merge upgrade to Minimalism 2.3. That's if you don't already have GB Millennium installed; if so, you'll probly have to get a new computer.

Comment: I second the sentiment. In my view, simple constituent and polar questions like (2) and (3) do not conform to an analysis that acknowledges binary branching only.